# Processing images with file type .ntf

Tags: python, raster, gdal, band, nitf

I am use to posting in Stack Overflow, but it seems this question is best geared towards the GIS Stack Exchange. I need  to understand the .ntf file types for satellite images. I am in grad school and studying about applications of ML, both supervised and unsupervised classification, to different interests. One of those areas of interest is satellite images. I have tried to do my best due-dilligence and research everything I can take in regarding images from remote sensors, including rasters/vectors, diffrent file types and processing techniques. A few of my references are:
[USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-remote-sensing-and-what-it-used?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products) 
[NOAA](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/remotesensing.html) 
esri 
[ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-raster-data.htm)

However, many of the papers I have read on ML and satellite image processing utilize .tif or .jpeg formats. I am having a *very* difficult time processing these .ntf files. From what I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Imagery_Transmission_Format) , [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/nitf.html), & [Purdue](ftp://ftp.ecn.purdue.edu/jshan/ERDAS_Library/2011help/html/wf_NITF/NITF_Overview.html) is that **.ntf** file-types are used by the government and are basically a grouping of multiple segments under one file:

from [L3 Harris](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/BackgroundNITFNSIFFormat.html#Image)

- Security Segments
- Image Segments
- Graphic/Symbol Segments
- Label Segments
- Annotation Segments
- Text Segments Data
- Extension Segments
- Display Levels

I am hoping to train a simple unsupervised method (kmeans) to some of the images of this file type OR simply convert them, both of which are giving me trouble. For example, when using python I can utilize `gdal` to get a lot of good information, such as metadata, bands, and raster. However, all the images seem to have only one band and this is giving issues when trying to applying `sklearn.cluster` as the input is expected to be more than 1D.

Is there a different way to get the image data to be used in classification tasks?

Very simple for classification, just want to group by pixel - which, I am guessing is the issue since band 1 == black&white. I may be completely ignorant as well so someone do tell me to shut it.

I will include the current method below and perhaps someone can direct me to good resource for more enlightenment?

```py
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

raster_img = gdal.Open('image_A.ntf')
band_n = raster_img.RasterCount
#band_n
#output > 1
raster01 = raster_img.GetRasterBand(1)
raster01_Arr = raster01.ReadAsArray()

#Trying to reshape for KMeans fails

classes = {'land':0,'water':1}
n_classes = len(classes)

rows, cols, bands = raster01_Arr.shape
##Error! 3 vars declared, only 2 values

rows, cols = raster01_Arr.shape

rows
#>4000
cols
#>4700

X = raster01_Arr.reshape(rows,cols,1) #added one for band

kM = KMeans(n_cluster = n_classes, random_state = 2).fit(X)
#fails, expects 2D, only received 1D
```

Example .ntf format files can be found [here](https://gwg.nga.mil/ntb/baseline/software/testfile/Nitfv2_1/scen_2_1.html)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a single focused question here.

Comment: Sorry! To be more succinct, how can I process raster data from these file types without crashing memory (when using sklearn)?

Comment: Okay, now rewrite the Question to ask just this one question. Include details of the crash you are experiencing. Imagine Sgt. Joe Friday standing there, peppering you with, "Just the facts," exhortations.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches that might help.

- `raster01_Arr` should already be a two-dimensional array. Can you try skipping the reshape step and passing it directly to the `KMeans.fit()`? That seemed to work as I followed your example code with a test file.

In other tools that would help read/process/convert, I'd look at:

- [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) converts to other formats, e.g. `gdal_translate -of GTiff input.ntf output.tiff`
- [`rasterio`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provides a simpler-than-osgeo wrapper around reading/writing raster data in Python

Answer (score 1):

Here is the breakdown of how I was able to accomplish it, with a lot of help from [arcgeospatial"](http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/k-means-sentinel-2-python/). See below, I hope it helps someone that also has troubles!

[image: Original .ntf]

[image: Output from KMeans]

```py
$ from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
$ from sklearn import cluster
$ from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
$ import numpy as np
$ imageA_file = gdal.Open('i_3001a.ntf')
$ imageA_file.RasterCount
1
$ band = imageA_file.GetRasterBand(1)
$ img = band.ReadAsArray()
$ X = img.reshape((-1,1))
$ k_means = cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=4,batch_size = 100)
$ k_means.fit(X)
MiniBatchKMeans(batch_size=100, compute_labels=True, init='k-means++',
                init_size=None, max_iter=100, max_no_improvement=10,
                n_clusters=4, n_init=3, random_state=None,
                reassignment_ratio=0.01, tol=0.0, verbose=0)
$ X_cluster = k_means.labels_
$ X_cluster = X_cluster.reshape(img.shape)
```